# How to set max interations for QP subproblem of sqp optimization?

Tags: octave

I am trying to run a nonlinear optimization using Octave's [sqp](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Nonlinear-Programming.html#Nonlinear-Programming) solver, but I'm getting a warning that says "sqp: QP subproblem failed to converge in 200 iterations". From what I understand, the sqp (nonlinear) solver makes successive calls to the QP (quadratic) solver. But I only seem to be able to set the max iterations for the initial sqp call--not the QP subcalls.

The two things I tried so far were setting the max iterations to 500 in the sqp call - `sqp (x0, phi, g, h, lb, ub, maxiter=500)` - and including the line `optimset('MaxIter',500)` at the start of my script, but both of those only set the max iterations for the sqp solver and not the QP subproblems. Is there any way to set the max iterations for the QP subproblems as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible as you can see in the QP call inside the SQP implementation: http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/8c648c3a2c8f/scripts/optimization/sqp.m#l412

Please start a feature request on Savannah: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/bugs.html